# Django - Join first row of a related table

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Say I have the tables `Products` and `Images`, where a product can have many images. When fetching a list of products for a search results page, how can include the first product image as a thumbnail?

What would be the best way to do when also taking performance into consideration? (number of queries, memory, overall time, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to fetch the image directly in template. Rather than building a list in view and pass it in template, as there would be on number of items.

So I will recommend to implement a method in `Products` model that finds first image and returns url for it.

models.py

```
def Products(models.Model):
    #your fields

    def get_image_url(self):
        try:
            img = self.images_set.filter()[0] #get first image
            return img.url()
        except Exception:
            return None
```

In template:

```
{% for p in product_list %}
     {# render product and add image #}
     <img href="{{p.get_image_url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would cause a relatively large amount of queries no?

Answer (score 0):

If you need performance boost w/o much architecture reworking, de-normalization is a first way to try:

```
class Product(models.Model): # instead of Products as convention
    first_image = models.ImageField(editable=False, null=True)
```

Then maintaining the `first_image` when `Product.image_set` get updated through signal.

Also, you could even store the "weakref" inside some dumped field (use this when you really need it :)

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # from django-jsonfield, store raw values of ImageField of the Images model
    extra = JSONField()
    def first_image(self):
        image = self.extra.get('image')
        return models.ImageField.attr_class(None, models.ImageField(), image) if image else None
```

Other simple ways may include

- Load the first images in batch and use them in template loop per `Product()`. The first images need to be marked for easy query.
- directly store `first_image` in `Product` instead of being an `Images`. This works fine for  simple sites w/o too much management requirements .